# Is there a way to use the NOT operator on Amazon?

Tags: search, amazon

Is there a way to use the NOT operator on Amazon?

I'm trying to find books, and am finding it very frustrating to be unable to filter out books I don't want based on author or subject.

Comment: Just sent an email to Amazon, had a phone call with one of their reps, and left feedback regarding this issue of getting way too many irrelevant search result. Especially when you then try to sort by low price. I have found that by selecting a category that hopefully is close to what I need it is slightly better, but of course then it's not exactly as my search. I have left feedback that when the search results become irrelevant that I quit, and don't buy. If we all would follow this principle perhaps Amazon would change, because it seem they have ignored all complaints regarding this issue fo

Comment: @kdsdata looks like they still haven't heard us four years later...

Comment: conversely putting something in brackets makes it a MUST have keyword:

ie: usb-c 4 port hub (3.2)

This gives me only USB 3.2 hubs! Finally! Amazon search has always been terrible and I've bought the wrong items many times by not paying attention.. one time it was as stupid as AA batteries when I wanted AAA.. So annoyed when the box of non-returnable AA's showed up!

Comment: @MichaelFever you say brackets `[` `]` but you are using parenthesis `(` `)`.   Which do you mean?

Comment: @StingyJack in British English (and maybe others) "brackets" means the curvy ones which American English calls "parenthesis"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

UPDATE: This feature does NOT work as of June 2019.

You can use the minus sign (`-`) in front of the terms you want to exclude from the search results.

For example: `stephen king -dark`

I found that adding the item to be excluded wrapped in () makes the NOT operator work

i.e. `gem (-rocks)` will return a search where rocks was excluded
above would be: `stephen king (-dark)`

Comment: and yet `ECC -"NON-ECC" -"NON ECC" -"non-ECC" -"Non-ECC"` STILL returns boat loads of product titles containing "NON-ECC" making it feel almost impossible to find ecc ram.

Comment: @user3338098: Try this: `ecc ram -non`

Comment: I think you have to keep it very simple.  I tried `-"extension cord"` and got nothing but hits with "extension cord" in the title.  Then, I tried just `-cord` and the hits looked much better.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar This `-` sign trick does not work anymore : ["Quick Charge" -Type -"USB C"](https://www.amazon.fr/s?k=%22Quick+Charge%22+-Type+-%22USB+C%22&rh=n%3A430315031&__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss)

Comment: Dead answer.

It used to work, but as a few have said here, this method is broken, and there seems to be no current way to exclude keywords in Amazon search.

Comment: 2019 article with Amazon search syntax: https://techboomers.com/t/amazon-search

Comment: That techboomers article is useless… does not mention a single “advanced” search option. 

Obviously Amazon believes that there is some inherent value in making products difficult to find.  Advanced searching for products is a no brainer.  Probably related to impulse buying. 

They should include Advanced Search capabilities for Prime members. 

Comment: This definitely does _NOT_ work as of June 2019

Comment: Still not working 2 years later. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: As far as I can remember, this hasn't worked at Amazon in at least 20 years.

Comment: @Ram: it used to work fine for many years pre-2015ish, Amazon seems to have intentionally broken it

Comment: That doesn't work on amazon.

Comment: Same as most of search engines; they don't like users to have fine-tuned control on results, otherwise they loose their marketing power.

Comment: Does not seem to do anything for me.  Adding `-solar` returns loads of results with solar in the title of the product

Comment: I'm confused on your answer; I can't tell whether to upvote it or not. You say "You can use the minus sign (-) in front of the terms you want to exclude from the search results." but then "I found that adding the item to be excluded wrapped in () makes the NOT operator work"... which is it?! Regardless, I tried both, and neither work. This site really needs a button to flag "doesn't work anymore" with a vote count icon next to it, would save me at least a lot of time.

Comment: `-` alone didn't work but with `(-term)` it works

Comment: Seems to be working now in 2023

Answer (score 60):

Unfortunately, Amazon does not regard the NOT operator anymore (negative keyword search).

Workaround: use **Google Search** with for example:

`site:amazon.com lightbulbs -led`

This will give you all lightbulbs that are not LED.

Of course, you don't have the sorting-order of Amazon's search engine anymore. But it serves the purpose.

However, with Google Search you can get latest products by using the `after:yyyy-mm-dd` search parameter.

Example:

`site:amazon.com lightbulbs -led after:2021-01-01`

Comment: Hilarious that Amazon's pushed us to use an internet search engine to exclude results, which shows shopping alternatives. Maybe it's better to just exclude `site:amazon` from the internet search. Brilliant answer with the `after:` param though, thanks. :thumbs-up:

Comment: Hilarious that I am searching for magnifier and want to exclude the term of `LED`

Answer (score 19):

As of July 2015, at least there is no reliable way to use a NOT operator.

At least on Amazon.de searching for `hard drive -usb` will reduce the number of USB drives, but already the last result on the first page contained "USB" in the title.

Searching for `tischventilator -usb` (German for table fan) on the other hand pushes usb devices even more to the top of the result list than just searching for `tischventilator`.

On Amazon.com again, adding `-usb` to `table fan` has the intended effect.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results using your search terms on either amazon.com or amazon.co.uk but indeed amazon.de IS doing the wrong thing. What I also notice is that it's not searching for the german term I copy pasted but instead for the translated term "Table fan -USB" which may be the reason you're seeing incorrect results.

Comment: have the same problem here

Comment: Still true. minus does not weed out the results you do not want, though it used to.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to this answer, I've discovered that amazon respects + before a keyword too!

For example: Radeon +7990 will give you exactly 7990's results and not variations on models like 6990 or 7970 like it normally does.

Comment: This seems to improve the accuracy of search results, but only partially. It looks to me as though prepending `+` to a search term just assigns extra weight to that term, rather than acting as a Boolean operator that excludes all non-matching results. So, non-matching results *do* still show up, and still frustratingly often; just not as often as if `+` weren't used. (I guess Amazon is using some kind of fuzzy logic for its search engine. Whatever the underlying reasoner is doing, though, it is doing it badly. Amazon's search engine is awful.)

Comment: It's hard to keep track of what amazon is doing since I can't find any documentation on their search but the answer worked at the time, it just seems to have changed and not performing exactly same anymore. For that matter I can't get - to properly work either!.

Comment: Maverik, yep, not your fault. Amazon should (a) have a search engine that works (i.e. that returns only relevant results), and (b) should document it properly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't implying that you're implying it's my fault. Just shared my own frustration :D but yes wish there was proper docuementation. Re: (a) pretty sure it's intentional -> upselling stuff